# Why is checking error less than 1 sufficient for Newton's method square root estimation integer?

Tags: algorithm

Problem is from this link: https://leetcode.com/problems/sqrtx

My question is the line `while (Math.abs(x0-x1) >= 1)` condition. I don't understand why the moment that condition breaks, the answer would be the floor of x1. Is there no case where the break condition occurs at something like x1 equals 7 point something, but the true square root is 6 point something, giving the wrong answer of 7 when the actual answer is 6?

From my testing, this seems to be an invariant, but I don't understand why.

This is the Newton's Method solution:

```java
class Solution {
  public int mySqrt(int x) {
    if (x < 2) return x;

    double x0 = x;
    double x1 = (x0 + x / x0) / 2.0;
    while (Math.abs(x0 - x1) >= 1) {
      x0 = x1;
      x1 = (x0 + x / x0) / 2.0;
    }

    return (int)x1;
  }
}
```

Comment: I believe the `1` specified here is the error tolerance allowed for the value that you compute. However as you point out a tolerance of 1 does not guarantee that the value rounded to an integer will be correct. It seems to me that the code is not correct (if what is expected is to return the closest integer)

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev: who said that the expected result is the closest integer? If you follow the link (and I do understand why you might not want to), you'll see that in the expected result "the decimal digits are truncated, and only the integer part of the result is returned".

Comment: @rici in theory this may still not be true. For instance if the real answer is 2.9 (well imagine a sqrt that is close to an integer), the function may return 3

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev I can see what you're saying, and yet, if you start with a number like 1073610755 (where the true square root is 32765.99998...) the method still works, and outputs 32765.

Comment: In fact the method works for all 32-bit positive 2's complement numbers, when a `double` is encoded as 64-bit IEEE-754.

Comment: @ivaylo: that's true, actually. If the computations were precise, it couldn't happen, but doubles don't have infinite precision. Sorry. This is why isqrt is usually computed using integer arithmetic rather than doubles.

Comment: @user3386109: first counterexample is 314161²-1 (with 64-bit doubles).

Comment: @rici Yup, it can't possibly work for 64-bit values of `x`. At some point, even the starting value of `x` can't be exactly represented as a 64-bit `double`.

Comment: @user3386109 It still stored accurately to roughly 5 decimal places at the point of first failure.  So fails earlier than I might have expected.

Comment: @user3386109 a 64 bit float has a mantissa of 53 bits (the first an implied 1).  So 10 bits is about 3 digits, so that would be 15 digits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is indeed clever, and not at all obvious.

The update rule we have is `x1 = (x0 + x/x0)/2 = f(x0)`.

First question.  What is `f'(x0)`?

```
f'(x0) = d/dx0 (x0 + x/x0) / 2
       = (1 - x/x0^2) / 2
```

Let's note some facts.

1. If `sqrt(x) < x0`, then the derivative is positive.  So `f(x0)` is strictly increasing over `sqrt(x) < x0`.  But `f(sqrt(x)) = sqrt(x)`.  Therefore if `sqrt(x) < x0` then `sqrt(x) < f(x0)`.
2. The derivative is always `< 1`.  So `x0 - f(x0)` is also strictly increasing.  That's the size of the step.
3. We are treating `x` as a constant here.  But we should also note that (as long as `x0^2 < x`), the larger `x` is, the smaller the step size gets.

Enough Calculus, let's do something harder - algebra!

Let's try our best to have it give an answer of `k` when it should be giving an answer of `k-1`.  That means we want `x < k*k`.  The larger `x` is, the smaller the step, so we'll make `x` as big as we can - namely `k*k-1`

We want `k <= f(x0)`.  But we also want `x0 - f(x0) < 1`. Keeping in mind point 2, let's try `x0 = k+1` and see where our next point lands.

But

```
f(k+1) = f(x0)
       = (x0 + x/x0) / 2
       = ((k+1) + (k^2 - 1)/(k+1)) / 2
       = ((k+1)^2 + (k^2 - 1)) / (2 * (k+1))
       = ((k^2 + 2k + 1) + (k^2 - 1)) / (2 * (k+1))
       = (2 k^2 + 2k) / (2 * (k+1))
       = (2 * (k+1) * k) / (2 * (k+1))
       = k
```

And whoops - `x0 - f(x0) == 1` which fails our condition.  Increasing `x0` from there will result in a larger step size (which means we aren't finished yet), and decreasing it gives us the right answer.

So the condition is proven mathematically correct.

But...let's test it.  Here is a test in Python.

```
def my_sqrt(x):
    x0 = x
    x1 = (x0 + x/x0)/2
    while (1 <= abs(x1 - x0)):
        x0 = x1
        x1 = (x0 + x/x0)/2
    return int(x1)

for i in range(2, 1000000):
    if i == my_sqrt(i * i - 1):
        print(i)
```

This finds that if `k` is in `(314161, 599326, 599327, ...)` then you get the wrong answer.  Why?  Because it is a delicate condition, and even one [ulp](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-math-ulpx-function/) of error can mess up the answer.

Comment: Interesting: [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_square_root#Stopping_criterion) only makes the claim and there's a "citation needed" :-)

Comment: @KellyBundy Be my guest in adding a link to this answer as a citation.

Comment: So how do you fix it? (1) Do the computation one more time after the stop condition is reached (eg. replace `return int(x1);` with `return int((x1 + x/x1)/2)`. That will handle every number less than 0x4000001²-1 (only tested with x²-1, but I think the statement is correct). (2) Do the computation with 64-bit integers. However, you need to change the end test slightly: `while x0 > x1:` and `return x0`.

Comment: @rici Those work.  Or take the Wikipedia suggestion and change 1 to something smaller, like 0.5.